# How to select rows where multiple joined table values meet selection criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following sample table schema

Customer Table

```
CustID
1
2
3
```

Invoice Table

```
CustID InvoiceID

1       10
1       20
1       30
2       10
2       20
3       10
3       30
```

The objective is to select all customers who have an InvoiceID value of 10 and 20 (not OR). So, in this example customers w/ CustID=1 and 2 would be returned.

How would you construct the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT c.custid
    FROM CUSTOMER c
    JOIN INVOICE i ON i.custid = c.custid
   WHERE i.invoiceid IN (10, 20)
GROUP BY c.custid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.invoiceid) = 2
```

The key thing is that the counting of `i.invoiceid` needs to equal the number of arguments in the `IN` clause.

The use of `COUNT(DISTINCT i.invoiceid)` is in case there isn't a unique constraint on the combination of custid and invoiceid -- if there's no chance of duplicates you can omit the DISTINCT from the query:

```
  SELECT c.custid
    FROM CUSTOMER c
    JOIN INVOICE i ON i.custid = c.custid
   WHERE i.invoiceid IN (10, 20)
GROUP BY c.custid
  HAVING COUNT(i.invoiceid) = 2
```

Comment: This will restrict the query result to customers with 10 and 20 ONLY. Leave out the having clause to allow for customers with 10, 20, and also additional invoices, depending on your need.

Comment: @ulty4life: I don't think you are correct. The WHERE clause will filter out all of the other InvoiceID records before the COUNT, leaving only the 10's and 20's to count.

Answer (score 1):

The Group By answers will work unless it is possible for there to be multiples of CustID/InvoiceId in the Invoice table. Then you might get some unexpected results. I like the answer below a little better because it mirrors more closely the logic as you are describing it.

```
Select CustID
From Customer
Where
  Exists (Select 1 from Invoice Where CustID=Customer.CustID and InvoiceID=10)
and
  Exists (Select 1 from Invoice Where CustID=Customer.CustID and InvoiceID=20)
```

Comment: Your statement about duplicates is incorrect -- see my comments about using COUNT vs COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustID
    from InvoiceTable
    where InvoiceID in (10,20)
    group by CustID
    having COUNT(distinct InvoiceID) = 2
```