# Getting table rows where multiple foreign table criteria need to be satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select rows where multiple joined table values meet selection criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047314/how-to-select-rows-where-multiple-joined-table-values-meet-selection-criteria)

I have a `Users` table, and an `Optons` table which contains some options for each user. Each user can have multiple options selected.

This is how tables look like:

```
-- this is where user names are stored
create table Users 
(
    ID int, 
    UserName varchar(255)
)

-- this table contains options 
-- (one flag per row)
create table Options
(
    ID NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT int, 
    Flag int, 
    User_ID int // foreign key
)
```

I would like to get all users which have two certain options set, but only if **both** of them are set.

For example, this will return users where any of the options is set:

```
-- find all users with flags 1 and 2 set
select u.UserName from Users u 
    inner join Options o on o.User_ID = u.ID
    where o.Flag in (1, 2)
```

How can I make it return all users which have two entries (for flags 1 and 2) in the `Options` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost correct but you need to count the number instances of the records and should be equal to the number of parameters in your `where` clause.

```
SELECT u.UserName 
FROM Users u 
     INNER JOIN Options o 
        ON o.User_ID = u.ID
WHERE o.Flag in (1, 2)
GROUP BY u.UserName 
HAVING COUNT(o.Flag) = 2
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I've found the answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4047314/1488067) in the meantime.

Comment: If the user has two entries of o.flag = 2 and none for o.flag =1  this query would incorrectly return the record. That's why you need `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FLAG) = 2` not `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw it out there:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.UserName 
FROM Users u 
JOIN Options o ON u.User_ID = o.ID AND o.Flag=1
JOIN Options p ON u.User_ID = p.ID AND p.Flag=2
```